# How can I retrieve records from a Google Spreadsheet in JSON format?

Tags: google-sheets, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from Google Spreadsheets with no success.

I've gone through this:

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#RetrievingTables

and this:

[Simple example of retrieving JSON feeds from Spreadsheets Data AP](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html)

I already set my spreadsheet as public (even though it shouldn't) just to take authentication out of the equation.

I have no problem getting the data in Atom/XML. However when I pass the parameter `alt=json`, I get the following error message:

> The spreadsheet at this URL could not
>   be found. Make sure that you have the
>   right URL and that the owner of the
>   spreadsheet hasn't deleted it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: searched their forums? http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/label?lid=4c7c98a970adf580&hl=en

Comment: Apparently Google Data APIs are essentially deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with the API (and banging my head against the monitor), I found out that in order to retrieve data *in JSON format* from a public spreadsheet you actually have to go through a second process called "Publish to the web" in the Spreadsheets GUI.

What's the reason for this? I haven't found out yet, but judging by the error messages I was getting, I will call it "A BUG".

On a side note, thanks to the people that took the time to reply/edit my question

Comment: please consider posting this as a bug on their forum

Comment: The reason is that Google wants to protect your data. It allows only the owner to publish that data to the world. It is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This thread looks like it might help you. Last comment states:

> Well, I just realized I should be using the /feeds/cells/ instead of /feeds/list/

This provides the cells in separate JSON properties like I need.  Sorry, I got so caught up trying to make sense of the list format that I completely forgot to look at the cells feed.

[Forum Topic](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=531e2447017b45de&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for pointing my to the forums, they didn't address my particular issue but were helpful to understand the problem in a broader sense.

Comment: glad i could help some - i thought for sure it would of fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Power Tools Add-on where you can export selected range into XML or JSON. See the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuubKrtejNQ).

[image]